# Hacer print de una lista en imagen

Tags: python, spyder

He estado investigando pero no he sido capaz de conseguirlo. Estoy intentando hacer que un print de una lista normal como por ejemplo lista=['a','c'] me saque por consola una imagen, es decir, que me imprima esa lista pero en formato imagen.

¿Esto en Python es posible?

```
import docx
import re

texto = []
document = docx.Document('prueba.docx')

for parrafo in document.paragraphs:
    # Aquí eliminas los caracteres que no quieres en el párrafo
    p = re.sub(r'[.,:;]', '', parrafo.text)
    # Aquí divides el párrafo en palabras y lo añades a la lista
    texto.extend(p.split())

print(texto)
```

Mi idea es que me saque en imagen el print de esa función, que al final son las palabras de un documento de texto

Comment: Entiendo que una consola es, por definición, una interfaz de solo texto. Por tanto, la respuesta a tu pregunta es: No puedes mostrar una imagen en una consola.